# What's the name for expressions like "food, glorious food"?

Tags: expressions, syntactic-analysis

Is there a literary term for the construction of the phrase *food, glorious food?* I'm assuming something related to its brevity and repetition.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd call them song lyrics ;-)

Comment: It is an example of [diacope.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacope)